# WPF Merged Dictionaries

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, material-design-in-xaml

i'm trying to use MaterialDesginThemes and HandyControl ResourceDictionary together but after i run my application it seems that it only recognising Handycontrol recourses at then i find out that application resources can only recognize the last line in the recourse dictionary can any one help how to fix this problem

```
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Light.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Primary/MaterialDesignColor.Blue.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Accent/MaterialDesignColor.Purple.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/HandyControl;component/Themes/SkinDefault.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/HandyControl;component/Themes/Theme.xaml"/>
               
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: The lookup order is to check the resource dictionary itself and then iterate through the merged dictionaries in reverse order. It’s not that WPF won’t check the other entries in the MergedDictionaries - it’s just that it will stop once it find the resource its looking for. Since you don’t say what you are trying or what is in those it’s hard to offer any suggestions. But think of it this way. If you have a TextBox in your window and in each of those mergeddictionaries you have a style for TextBox, WPF will end up using the first one it finds which in this case is the one in the Theme.xaml file

Comment: would you show me how to solve this problem I'm confusing  thanks

Comment: You didn’t explain what the actual problem was, what you were seeing or what you were expecting so I cannot offer any solutions.

Comment: I don’t know what is in those resource dictionaries but like I said - wpf will use the first resource that matches what it is looking for. So assuming each of those has Style’s for the same controls (e.g. TextBox) then wpf is going to take the first one it finds. What are you expecting it would have done (assuming that is the problem)?

Comment: For example maybe your intention is to allow the end user to choose which theme to load. If that’s the case then don’t put any into the MergedDictionaries xaml. Instead at runtime create a ResourceDictionary, set its Source (using the [pack uri notation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)) and add that to the MergedDictionaries and remove the one you added previously (if you are switching between them).